Convergence and boundedness when a constant is added or multiplied
I am given that $X_{n} = O_p(a_n)$ and $Y_n - c = O_p(a_n)$ where $a_n$ is a sequence that goes to zero. Given this, I want to show that $X_{n}/Y_n = O_p(a_n)$.
Since $a_n$ goes to zero, we can say $X_{n} = o_p(1)$ and similarly $Y_n - c = o_p(1)$. This inturn implies $Y_n - c = O_p(1)$. c here is a constant. If we are saying $Y_n - c$ is stochastically bounded, can we also say $Y_n$ itself is. And so if $X_{n} = o_p(1)$ or converges in probability to 0, then $X_{n}/Y_n$ also converges in probability to 0? Additionally, can we say since $X_{n} = o_p(1)$, so is $X_{n}/c$?
I want to use the fact that $X_n/Y_n = X_n/c + (X_n/Y_n)(c-Y_n)(1/c)$ to arrive at the needed result. If there are better ways, let me know.

Some pointers that OP could play with:
$\bullet$ Given $Y_n-c=O_\mathrm P(a_n) , $ where $a_n\to 0.$ This implies $Y_n-c=o_\mathrm P(1). $ By definition, for each $\varepsilon > 0,$ there exists $N_\varepsilon\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\geq N_\varepsilon,$ $$\mathrm P(|Y_n-c|<\varepsilon)>1-\varepsilon.$$
$\bullet$ One can then write $\mathrm P(c-\varepsilon<Y_n<c+\varepsilon) > 1-\varepsilon\implies \mathrm P\left(\frac{1}{c+\varepsilon}<\frac 1 {Y_n}<\frac{1}{c-\varepsilon}\right) > 1-\varepsilon,~\forall n\geq N_\varepsilon.$
Can $Y_n^{-1}$ be expressed as $O_\mathrm P(1) $?
Verify that if it is possible.
$\bullet$ If so, can one write $X_nY_n^{-1}=O_\mathrm P(a_n) O_\mathrm P(1)$? Is it justified to conclude the result?
